# How to send variable with auth_request in nginx?

Tags: nginx, authorization

I'm trying to send a variable via the `auth_request` directive so that I can then use the variable for the actual authorization. I'm trying to do it with a GET request, but if other methods work that is fine. It will also work if there is a way to reference the `auth_request`. I'm trying to create one location that can verify every app instead of a different location for each app.

```
    auth_request /auth?app=myapp;
...
    location /auth {
         internal;
    
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/auth?PASS_GET_VARIABLE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the variable `app=myapp` is already being passed. The way to do this is with a `rewrite` and changing the `proxy_pass` URI.

```
auth_request /auth?app=myapp;

location /auth {
    internal;

    rewrite ^/auth(.*) /portal/auth$1;    

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

If no URI is specified, the location match is passed as the URI. So in this example, `/auth?app=myapp` would get changed to `/portal/auth?app=myapp`, and it would be passed along.